# Importing files with Solr Cell / Tika is mixing metadata fields with content

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I'm indexing some files using Solr (version 6.6.0) and using the ExtractingRequestHandler approach to deal with things like PDF files.  This works mostly fine, as the file is indexed and searchable.  But there is one weird quirk I don't understand,and which is undesirable.

Here's the problem:  when I index a PDF this way, the "content" field winds up with a bunch of "metadata stuff" mixed in with the actual content.  Here's an example of what I get after indexing one of the sample PDF's shipped with Solr:

```
"content":[" \n \n date 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n pdf:PDFVersion 1.3  \n xmp:CreatorTool Microsoft Word  \n stream_content_type application/pdf  \n Keywords solr, word, pdf  \n access_permission:modify_annotations true  \n access_permission:can_print_degraded true  \n subject solr word  \n AAPL:Keywords solr, word, pdf  \n dc:creator Grant Ingersoll  \n dcterms:created 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n Last-Modified 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n dcterms:modified 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n dc:format application/pdf; version=1.3  \n Last-Save-Date 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n access_permission:fill_in_form true  \n meta:save-date 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n pdf:encrypted false  \n dc:title solr-word  \n modified 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n cp:subject solr word  \n Content-Type application/pdf  \n stream_size 21052  \n X-Parsed-By org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser  \n X-Parsed-By org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser  \n creator Grant Ingersoll  \n meta:author Grant Ingersoll  \n dc:subject solr, word, pdf  \n meta:creation-date 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n created Thu Nov 13 13:35:51 UTC 2008  \n access_permission:extract_for_accessibility true  \n access_permission:assemble_document true  \n xmpTPg:NPages 1  \n Creation-Date 2008-11-13T13:35:51Z  \n resourceName /opt/fogcutter/solr-6.6.0/example/exampledocs/solr-word.pdf  \n access_permission:extract_content true  \n access_permission:can_print true  \n meta:keyword solr, word, pdf  \n Author Grant Ingersoll  \n producer Mac OS X 10.5.5 Quartz PDFContext  \n access_permission:can_modify true  \n solr-word \n \n  page   \n This is a test of PDF and Word extraction in Solr, it is only a test.  Do not panic.  \n  \n \n  "],
```

All I expect (and want) to see in that field is the

```
This is a test of PDF and Word extraction in Solr, it is only a test.  Do not panic.
```

bit.

Is there a setting I need to twiddle that controls this, or is this just the standard behavior, or what?

FWIW, my schema.xml does not have any copyField elements enabled, and I am using the **ClassicIndexSchemaFactory** in my solrconfig.xml file.

Edit: looks like I may be seeing the same basic issue as [this solr bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9178).  Still, if anybody has any additional insight to share, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have encournted the same question.
Finially I solved it by adding this in solrconfig.xml

```
<str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
<str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
```

which will make all the metadata and other fields not matched ignored_(not indexed not stored)

Comment: This only removes metadata from being indexed as separated fields, however, they are still being added to the content field what is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that I can strip out the metadata by selecting only body part of the xml created by the parser using the XPath property:

```
extractFormat=xml
xpath=/xhtml:html/xhtml:body//node()
```

Would be better if that could be done by some setting, but it doesn't seem like Tika would support it.

At least this solution gives reasonable results for highlighting alternative as with the metadata in the content field it is just an useless mess of unrelated strings that doesn't give user any clue.

Hope it helps.